# how to pass js value to flask route

Tags: javascript, flask, request, jinja2

This is my list where i tried to get the value of the of a tag

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% block body %}

<div onclick="pass()">
    <a href="#">{{list1[1]}} </a>
</div>
```

here i tried to get the value of a tag and have tried to pass info route

```
<script>
    function pass() {
        var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        var w = console.log(a[0].outerHTML);
        window.location = "/info/" + w;

    }
</script>
```

{% endblock %}

but show the following error

```
Not Found
http://127.0.0.1:5000/info/undefined
```

this is my info route

```
@app.route('/info', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def info():
    result = request.get_data
    print(result)
    return render_template('info.html', result=result)
```

why it's not displaying any  data of within a tag

**Thank you in Advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.location` simply opens an HTML page. `window.location = "/info/" + w;` creates a route `/info/w/` but you've only specified the route `/info`.

You need to send the `a` data to the server via a form and use Flask's request object to access it.